# how to use Query.limit and Query.skip?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parsing, tableview

I've spent about 13hrs/day for the past week but I can't seem to figure it out. I've scrolled to the ends of the web but I can't seem to implement 'query.skip' and 'query.limit' to my table correctly.

The 'user' is following people and each person has a lot of posts. I want to load the first 5, then load the next 5 as the user scrolls down the table.

*I have a total of 19 posts by the users we are following.*

**PROBLEM:**  when this runs the first time, everything works, but as i scroll past the 4th row, it SHOULD run, skip = 5 and limit = 10, so on so fourth. But when it runs the 'loadFollowersImages()' function it starts to load 15, objects, then 30, 46...everything repeats and doubles.

What am I doing wrong? why does it not skip to the limit and add 5 to the new limit.

my viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if resultsHasNameArray.count == 0 {

        // to start download 5 posts

        skip = resultsHasNameArray.count
        limit = resultsHasNameArray.count + 5

        getFollowingData() {

    }

}
```

Gets the list of people the user is following: In this case it's Two Users

```
func getFollowingData() {

    var followQuery = PFQuery(className: "follow")
    followQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

    var objects = followQuery.findObjects()

    for object in objects! {

        self.followArray.append(object.objectForKey("userToFollow") as! String) // stores all the usernames Current user is following
    }

    loadFollowersImages() // once we know who we are following, start to download their "posts"

}
```

returns Two Users: James & Amy

Now to download their posts: which is total of 19
First downloads 5 posts.

```
func loadFollowersImages(){

    var photoQuery = PFQuery(className: "PostPhoto")

    photoQuery.skip = skip!      // oringally to 0
    photoQuery.limit = limit!    // oringally to 5

    photoQuery.whereKey("username", containedIn: followArray)
    photoQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")

    photoQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            for object in objects!{

                self.resultsHasNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)
                self.resultsHasUserImageFile.append(object.objectForKey("userImageFile") as! PFFile)

                self.resultsTable.reloadData()

            }

        }
    }
```

returns 5 posts successfully.

Now, when the users scrolls down to the 5, row, it should run the above (loadFollowersImages()) method and add 5 to skip and 5 to limit (5, 10, respectively).

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row  == limit! - 1{   // when scrolling down, if our limit meets index path run

        skip = skip! + 5               // adds '5' to skip
        limit = limit! + 5             // adds '5' to limit

        loadFollowersImages()          // runs above method
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to change the limit, you just want to download the next 5 so the limit still 5 during all the interactions, the only number you should alter is the number of rows to skip, however this will require adjustments in the if condition as now you want to run the `loadFollowersImages` function when the row displayed is equal to the limit plus the number of rows already skipped, as below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row  == limit! + skip! - 1{   
        // when scrolling down, if our limit + rows skiped meets index path run
            skip = skip! + 5               // adds '5' to skip and limit is constante
            loadFollowersImages()          // runs above method
        }

    }
```